# Terminal Zsh error after just opening terminal on Mac Catalina

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I am getting a weird message after just opening the terminal and could not figure out the problem.

```
Last login: Wed Mar 31 11:10:55 on ttys000
/Users/rakesh/.zprofile:source:1: no such file or directory: /Users/rakesh/.profile
```

rakesh is Home folder name.  /.profile don't know what file it is??

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: In Terminal, you should type `cat ~/.zprofile` and include that output in your question.  Most likely your file includes a line like `source ~/.profile`.  You can create that file, or maybe better yet, remove that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For login shells (e.g when you open the terminal) that file is processed. In your case, that file not exists. You can create it:

```
touch ~/.profile
```

You have a description and difference described that include .profile here: [What is the difference between .profile and .bash_profile and why don't I have a .profile file on my system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83742/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-and-why-dont-i-have-a)

Comment: Thank you ...Saved my day and night....!!

Comment: Your welcome. I'm happy to help u.